# How to correctly get photo of contact?

Tags: android, photo, contacts

I have google contact linked with facebook contact (with photo) and skype contact (with photo).

I choose skype photo for contact (via address book application). Address book displays contact with chosen (skype) photo.

Start my app. Request photo id from ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI by contact id. "Load" photo to ImageView. All seems well – photo has been loaded. Finish my app.

I choose facebook photo for contact (via address book application). Address book displays contact with chosen (facebook) photo.

Start my app. Again request photo id by contact id. The received photo id differs from the previous id. "Load" photo to ImageView. Photo has not been loaded. LogCat: "relolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: ...". Why???

Some parts of my code:

```
Cursor photoCursor = managedQuery(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{ ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID },
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=?",
    new String[]{ contactId },
    null);

String photoId = photoCursor.getString(photoCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, photoIdByContatId);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
imageView.setImageURI(photoUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 Cursor photoCursor = managedQuery(

                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=?", 
                String.valueOf(ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.MIMETYPE+ "=?")},
               new String[]{contactId, 
String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) }
null);
```

Comment: MIMETYPE is necessary only for ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI. I get photo id from ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI.

Comment: If to try to receive photo id from ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI then will be returned two records with identical photo ids. These ids are similar to mine.